# Is there a norm making $C([0,1])$ into a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

The space $C([0,1])$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is an inner product space under the $L^2$-norm, but not complete. Equipped instead with the $L^\infty$-norm, it becomes complete but the norm is no longer induced by an inner product (in particular it does not satisfy the parallelogram law). This got me wondering: can we equip $C([0,1])$ with a norm which makes it into a Hilbert space?

Comment: What would be the trivial examples that would make it a Hilbert space?

Comment: @TheoBendit My mistake, a non-trivial semi-norm would make sense. In my head I was thinking of a zero norm. Edited!

Answer (score 10):

As a vector space, $C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ is isomorphic to $L^2\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$, since they both have Hamel bases with the same dimension (the cardinal of $\mathbb R$). So, if $\psi\colon C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)\longrightarrow L^2\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$, define $\lVert f\rVert=\bigl\lVert\psi(f)\bigr\rVert_2$.

Of course, this uses the Axiom of Choice. I don't know how to solve the problem without it.

Comment: ,Hi the key point then is why this isometric isomorphism $\psi\colon C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)\longrightarrow L^2\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ exist?

Comment: @yi_li **First** you define $\psi$ as a linear isomorphism from $C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ onto $L^2\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$; it exists, since these spaces have the same dimenssion. **Then** you define, for each $f\in C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$, $\|f\|$ as $\bigl\|\psi(f)\bigr\|_2$. Then $\psi$ becomes an isometry from $\left(C\bigl([0,1]\bigr),\|\cdot\|\right)$ onto $\left(L^2\bigl([0,1]\bigr),\|\cdot\|_2\right)$.